# Reading output from imagemagick subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, imagemagick

I am wanting to get the average brightness of a file in python. Having read a previous question [[Problem getting terminal output from ImageMagick's compare.exe ( Either by pipe or Python )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145508/problem-getting-terminal-output-from-imagemagicks-compare-exe-either-by-pipe]) I have come up with :

```
cmd='/usr/bin/convert {} -format "%[fx:100*image.mean]\n" info: >    bright.txt'.format(full)
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
with open('bright.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    x=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
return x
```

the previous question recommended the use of 'pythonmagick' which I can find but with no current documentation and very little recent activity. I could not work out the syntax to use it.

I know that my code is unsatisfactory but it does work.
Is there a better way which does not need 'shell=true' or additional file processing ?

Comment: I am not an expert on Python Wand, but you can do fx commands in Python Wand. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html

Comment: You can also use Python Pillow to get the mean of an image. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageStat.html

Answer (score 1):

This seems to works for me to return the mean as a variable that can be printed. **(This is a bit erroneous. See the correction near the bottom)**

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.6

import subprocess

cmd = '/usr/local/bin/convert lena.jpg -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:'

mean=subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
print (mean)
```

The result is 70.67860, which is returned to the terminal.

This also works with shell=False, if you parse each part of the command.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.6

import subprocess

cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/convert','lena.jpg','-format','%[fx:100*mean]','info:']

mean=subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
print (mean)
```

The result is 70.67860, which is returned to the terminal.

**The comment from `tripleee` below indicates that my process above is not correct in that the mean is being shown at the terminal, but not actually put into the variable.**

He suggested to use `subprocess.check_output()`. The following is his solution. (Thank you, tripleee)

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.6

import subprocess

filename = 'lena.jpg'
mean=subprocess.check_output(
    ['/usr/local/bin/convert',
     filename,
     '-format',
     'mean=%[fx:100*mean]', 
     'info:'], universal_newlines=True)
print (mean)
```

Prints: `mean=70.6786`

Comment: This doesn't capture the output in `mean`, it just gets printed on standard output *before* you try to `print` the value from Python.  You want `subprocess.check_output()` or its modern replacement `subprocess.run()` instead of `subprocess.call()`.

Comment: `@tripleee`. Thanks for the correction. I am a novice with Python. But I have posted a correction in my post with your solution.

Comment: Add `universal_newlines=True` to receive the output as a decoded string. The OS performs I/O on `bytes` buffers in Python 3 by default. (Alternatively, `decode` the `bytes` object separately; but that's a hassle because then you need to specify the correct encoding.)

Comment: The `b` and the quotes are not part of the value, they are just Python's annotations to disambiguate the `repr` version.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `repr version`. But how would I take the returned variable and use that in some further calculations when it has the b and single quotes?

Comment: `decoded = b'foo'.decode('ascii')` gets you a string from a byte string. The `b'...'` decoration is just Python's annotation for a byte string; the actual string is the stuff between the quotes. Compare `u'unicode string'`, `r'raw string'`, etc. This is a common FAQ; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918836/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-b-prefix-in-a-string-in-python and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr

Comment: `@tripleee`. Thanks I learned something new today. That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably improve the subprocess, and eliminate the temporary text file with `Popen` + `PIPE`.

```py
cmd=['/usr/bin/convert',
     full,
     '-format',
     '%[fx:100*image.mean]',
     'info:']
pid = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = pid.communicate()
return float(out)
```

ImageMagick also ships with the `identify` utility. The same method could be achieved with...

```py
cmd=['/usr/bin/identify', '-format', '%[fx:100*image.mean]', full]
```

It might be worth exploring if it's worth working directly with ImageMagick's shared libraries. Usually connected through C-API (pythonmagick, wand, &etc). For what your doing, this would only increase code-complexity, increase module dependancies, but in no way improve performance or accuracy.

Comment: There is no good reason to reimplement `subprocess.check_output()` or its modern replacement `subprocess.run()`. Generally avoid `subprocess.Popen()` unless you really know what you are doing.